# What/which difference

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Do both the following sentences mean the same? If not, what's the difference?

1- Which colleges in India are run by the right wing students' group?

2- What colleges in India are run by the right wing students' group?

Answer (score -1):

The two sentences are pretty similar. Which is usually used to make a choice , for example. Which school is better. School A or B? What is has many possibilities. For example , What colour are your shoes?(It can be blue , green or red , etc.) 
In my opinion , i feel that the second sentence is better than
 the first.